# How to disable a YouTube comment notification?

Tags: youtube

Once I was looking at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTUQ8Idrowg and commented on the top comment

[image: screen shot of comment thread]

Since then I get notifications about each new reply. I clicked on the three dots on the notification and pressed "Turn off reply updates", but I still get notifications if someone replies to the original top comment.

[image: screen shot of notifications]

I also found the option to disable comments in general from other videos.

[image: screen shot of options menu]

But I only want to disable notifications for replies on that particular comment. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it is not possible to disable notifications for any individual comment, no. At least not in other ways than the ones you found, both of which seem to be imperfect.

I recommend sending feedback at the bottom of any YouTube page (if you're using https://www.youtube.com/new: in the avatar menu) to let YouTube know that you care about the bell functionality.